# GMail or Office 365 for small businesses with LOTS of domains

Tags: email, spam, g-suite, gmail, microsoft-office-365

Sorry if not the right place to ask, I'm pretty new here (mostly post programming questions on SO).

I work for a small company, about 5 employees, but we have 5 different domains we use for sending and receiving email.  We currently use a shared hosted server for email, but other people on the server keep getting the server blacklisted for sending SPAM, so every time they get a virus, our outgoing email stops working.

We want to use either Google or Microsoft because every other anti-spam system we have tried produces too many false-positives (even 1 lost email can cost us a lot of money).  We don't mind paying $4 or $5/month per employee, but as far as I can tell they want that price per "email inbox".  So we would be 5 employees x 5 domains = 25, and that's assuming we don't mind using aliases for the generic stuff like sales@domain.com and info@domain.com.

Do they have plans that are more friendly for small businesses like ours, that better reflect our actual email needs/volume, or are we so unique that we don't have options with these guys and have to keep using the less reliable other options?

I'm not really interested in a dedicated server or trying to manage something ourselves.  We get a huge amount of spam (as I assume most most domains with websites do) and only "the big guys" can really handle it well.  I don't imagine we get 5 times more than other small businesses with 5 employees though, so don't think we should have to pay 5 times more just because we like to use different domains for email/products/websites vs sub-domains or having all products on one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O365's pricing isn't per domain. So in your case you could have the 5 employees and the 5 domains and just be charged per user.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2013/05/30/office-365-with-multiple-domains.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819265.aspx

Comment: So if I setup eselk@foo.com and eselk@bar.com (one as an alias I assume), I can use both of those with no real *restrictions and only be charged for 1 mailbox?  *I can send and receive with either, and will not have any weird "sent on behalf of" email headers or anything like that?  The only catch, vs multiple mailboxes, is that I'll only have 1 mailbox (POP/IMAP/etc)? (so that's how they avoid people abusing the system)

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: That's awesome!  Thanks -- might finally, after years of suffering, have this email issue resolved.